# ROUND to reduce decimals doesn't give expected results

Tags: sql-server

I have these 2 tables:

`Project` table:

```
+-------------+-------------+
| project_id  | employee_id |
+-------------+-------------+
| 1           | 1           |
| 1           | 2           |
| 1           | 3           |
| 2           | 1           |
| 2           | 4           |
+-------------+-------------+
```

Both columns are defined as `int`.

`Employee` table:

```
+-------------+--------+------------------+
| employee_id | name   | experience_years |
+-------------+--------+------------------+
| 1           | Khaled | 3                |
| 2           | Ali    | 2                |
| 3           | John   | 1                |
| 4           | Doe    | 2                |
+-------------+--------+------------------+
```

Int and varchar(30)

I'm making this simple calculation to get the average years of experience of all employees for each project, rounded to 2 digits:

```
SELECT 
    project_id, 
    ROUND(CAST(SUM(experience_years) AS decimal(3, 2)) / COUNT(*), 2) AS avg_years
FROM 
    employee_3 AS e
JOIN 
    project AS p ON e.employee_id = p.employee_id
GROUP BY
    project_id
```

The expected output is:

```
+-------------+---------------+
| project_id  | average_years |
+-------------+---------------+
| 1           | 2.00          |
| 2           | 2.50          |
+-------------+---------------+
```

But when I run it I get:

```
+-------------+----------------+
| project_id  | average_years  |
+-------------+----------------+
| 1           | 2.000000000000 |
| 2           | 2.5000000000000|
+-------------+----------------+
```

I tried changing the number -2 from to other numbers but it doesn't work, and I don't know what the problem really is. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try casting the `ROUND` as `decimal(3,2)`.

Comment: @DanGuzman I just did it and still not working sadly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ROUND does not change the data type, you need to CAST to the DECIMAL with the appropriate PRECISION and SCALE. PRECISION is the total number of digits. SCALE is the number of post decimal digits. 123.456 is DECIMAL(6,3). You should size your column to be able to accept the maximum value possible in your data. If it's possible your experience could run for 10-99 years, and you want 2 decimal places you'd need DECIMAL(4,2) - up to 99.99. A value of 100.00 would cause an arithmetic overflow.

```
DECLARE @ProjectEmployees TABLE (ProjectID INT, EmployeeID INT);
INSERT INTO @ProjectEmployees (ProjectID, EmployeeID) VALUES
(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 4);
DECLARE @Employees TABLE (EmployeeID INT, Name VARCHAR(10), ExperianceYears INT);
INSERT INTO @Employees (EmployeeID, Name, ExperianceYears) VALUES
(1, 'Kaled', 3), (2, 'Ali', 2), (3, 'John', 1), (4, 'Doe', 196);

SELECT pe.ProjectID, CAST(AVG(e.ExperianceYears+.0) AS DECIMAL(4,2)) AS AverageYears
  FROM @ProjectEmployees pe
    INNER JOIN @Employees e
      ON pe.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
 GROUP BY pe.ProjectID;
```

| ProjectID | AverageYears |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.00 |
| 2 | 99.50 |

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: question, You added the +.0 to Experience so  it prevents it to delet decimals before cast? Or what is the fuction of adding a 0. to experience? I dont get why u tought of adding it, sorry

Comment: It's a trick to allow the average to display in decimal years. `AVG(e.ExperianceYears)` would produce a `INT` result (2 or 99 rather than 2.00 or 99.5).